# Asynchronous Mysql connector

Tags: c++, mysql, c, asynchronous, boost-asio

Do any asynchronous connectors exist for Mysql that can be used within a C or C++ application? I'm looking for something that can be plugged into a [reactor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern) written in [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/asio/index.html).

[Edit:] Running a synchronous connector in threads is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but consider looking at the new Boost.Mysql library: https://anarthal.github.io/mysql/index.html

Comment: This seems great and would definitely be a good option to try.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am the library author. It has not yet been accepted in Boost, so expect breaking changes before it gets accepted. I hope for the review process to start soon. Should you have any problems/comments, feel free to open an issue in GitHub :)

Answer (score 6):

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?45,183339,183339
enjoy

Updated link to the original article showing how to do async mysql queries:

http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/async-mysql-queries-with-c-api/

Comment: The blocking connect is a serious issue in this implementation, but nonetheless is seem to do what I originally requested. The drizzle project (https://launchpad.net/drizzle) is working on an async client that will be backwards compatible with Mysql (mentioned here: http://www.oddments.org/?p=20)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a very different technologies: Twisted python (reactor-based IO) and sqlAlchemy (??). While searching for a solution, I found about an sAsync project that simply created a separate thread for sqlAlchemy and then responded to requests.

Given that ASIO is based on low level OS features (such as aio_read() or ReadFileEx() etc) and an OS-level reactor (or proactor, in Windows' case) I don't think you have another chance than emulating the 'asynchronousness' by similar means.

> Running a synchronous connector in threads is not an option

Think about it: the `libmysqlclient / mysqlclient.dll` you're using makes synchronous socket calls. The OS scheduler will correctly switch to another thread until the I/O is finished,  so what's the difference? (apart from the fact that you shouldn't make 2k threads for this..)

Edit: mysql_real_connect() supports an UNIX socket parameter. You can supposedly read yourself from the mysql server port and write to that UNIX socket only using ASIO. Like a proxyfication.

Answer (score 1):

[    *Running a synchronous connector in threads is not an option
Think about it: the libmysqlclient / mysqlclient.dll you're using makes synchronous socket calls. The OS scheduler will correctly switch to another thread until the I/O is finished*]

This is bugging me! - the 'another thread' could as easily be a second sync. connection to mysql, and should be handled by mysql just as it would another client altogether? My gutfeel is that it should work using multiple threads.

Comment: It will work in threads. But lets say that you want to have 100 connections vs one or more servers. Not that I imagine that anyone would do that, but accept it for the sake of the argument. Should I then spin up 100 thread (or even only 10 in a thread pool..)? Thats a fairly large overhead.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Connector/C++ is a C++ implementation of JDBC 4.0

The reference customers who use MySQL Connector/C++ are:
- OpenOffice - MySQL Workbench

Learn more: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?167,221298

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solution will be to create an asynchronous service that wraps a [standard connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html). You'll need to understand the ODBC APIs though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called DBSlayer that puts another layer in front of MySQL that you talk to through JSON. http://code.nytimes.com/projects/dbslayer

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using [libdrizzle](https://launchpad.net/drizzle)? i have used only an old version, from when it was a  separate project from drizzle, and i tested the asynchronous query features, but i never did any actual benchmarks worth mentioning.

Comment: I did take a quick look at the Drizzle project when I created this question (See my comment to the accepted answer). At that time they had an async client under way. I don't really know how that ended up.