# async c++ connector for mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, database, asynchronous, libdrizzle

googling about asynchronous /non-blocking connectors for mysql i went basically to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447/asynchronous-mysql-connector-for-c-or-c)

However, it's been 2 years and following whats happening on drizzle is a bit confusing at the moment. libdrizzle was a separate dependency at some point but they decided to merge it with the rest of the project. Are there other options for asynchronous database access from c++?

I've been looking at [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/), [ODB](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/) and [OpenDBX](http://www.linuxnetworks.de/doc/index.php/OpenDBX), but they all seem to be synchronous (require a separate thread for non-blocking operation)

Comment: What use is async connect?  You'll still have to synchronize to its completion, and it is doubtful there is much which can be usefully done during a long connect set up which can't as easily and quickly be done once the connection is established.

Comment: the connection is the least of the problems because its most of the time started and reused for a while: the real problem is that queries shouldn't block the current thread that could be used to do other things

Answer (score 3):

I had the same desire and came to the conclusion that it's not supported.  Even with the MySQL C API you can use the low-level functions to issue queries and wait for a response asynchronously, but you cannot ever get full asynchronous result collection--you always end up blocking from the time the first piece of the result is returned until the last.

I don't have direct experience with it, but I've read that Postgres does support full asynchrony (at least in the C API).

Answer (score 0):

I used to used [MySAC](http://www.arpalert.org/mysac.html) in my own project. It works well though is a little outdated. I just quote the description from their website:

> MySAC is a library that provides mechanisms for making asynchronous request to MySQL database.

And maybe you will interested in https://github.com/huxingyi/myc if you use libuv. It's a pure c mysql connector wrote by me, you can implement your own network layer or just use the implemented `libuv` based `uvmyc` inside the example folder.